# Custom metabox with App Store / Google Play links

Tags: metabox

I've got a issue when trying to setup our app portfolio. (have a look at [our portfolio page](http://dreamix-online.com/apps/texelvakantietv/))

Whats going on:
I created a custom post type with 'apps'. Every post I'm going to create is a project we worked on. In this post there might be 3 properties:

1) App store link 
2) Google Play store link
---- optional: ----
3) Intern app (no link)

Meanwhile, in our template this will be displayed:

Is there a store link?

If yes, make this image (http://www.dreamix-studio.com/images/ios_button.png) a link:

Else: 
Create this image (http://www.dreamix-studio.com/images/ios_inactive_button.png).

This also goes for the Google Store link.

How do I create this? And how do I create this in our template?

Comment: [How To Create Custom Post Meta Boxes In WordPress](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the use of this 'plugin' ([JareDatch](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress)). It works like a charm.

```
add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'cmb_sample_metaboxes' ); /** * Define the metabox and field configurations. ** @param  array $meta_boxes * @return array */ function cmb_sample_metaboxes( array $meta_boxes ) {

// Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
$prefix = '_cmb_';

$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id'         => 'appstore_link',
    'title'      => 'App Store',
    'pages'      => array( 'apps', ), // Post type
    'context'    => 'normal',
    'priority'   => 'high',
    'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
    'fields'     => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'App Store',
            'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
            'id'   => $prefix . 'app_store_link',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
    )
);

// Add other metaboxes as needed

return $meta_boxes;}

add_action( 'init', 'cmb_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes', 9999 ); function cmb_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes() { 
if ( ! class_exists( 'cmb_Meta_Box' ) )
    require_once 'init.php';}
```

And use the following in your theme:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_app_store_link', true) ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_app_store_link', true) ?>">
                    <img src="source.png" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_app_store_link', true) ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                </a>
```